# What is the exact meaning of the perpendicularLinks attribute?

Tags: javascript, attributes, diagram, jointjs

In JointJS there is a [`perpendicularLinks`](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper) parameter which "make links tend to get perpendicular to their associated objects".

This is not so clear for me. Anyone knows what is this option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `perpendicularLinks` option determines wether the last segment of the link should point to the center of the target object or be a horizontal/vertical line rather than a diagonal one. If `perpendicularLinks` is `true`, the link does not necessarily points to the center of the target object but to the closest point on the boundary of the target object where the last segment of the link is perpendicular.

Better than words, see the following images:

`perpendicularLinks`: `false`

[image]

`perpendicularLinks`: `true`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dave, it's much more clear :) And what about DEVS ports ?

Comment: For DEVS ports, the target element (the real DOM element the link should point to - we call such a DOM element a `magnet`) - is the port itself, so the link will get perpendicular to the port element (magnet), not the whole JointJS element.